# Ajax autocomplete not working with routing

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have registered 4 routes in global.asax file its working fine but when i have added another route then ajax autocomplete suggestion list not displaying.

routing code is as below.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup


        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


    }
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}", new System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));

    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute", "{Name}", "~/Default.aspx");
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("DetailsView", "view/{id}/{popid}", "~/frmListingDetails.aspx");

    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Listing", "{keyword}/{city}/{area}", "~/Listing.aspx");

    //RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Edit", "{id}/{vcode}", "~/Registration.aspx");
   // RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Regp2", "Upload/{regid}/{ecode}", "~/RegPart2.aspx");
    }
```

it is working fine but when i uncomment the commented root then ajax auto complete suggestion list not displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

to RegisterRoutes function.

By adding this ignore statement, you allow WebResource.axd to run properly.